# Proving set equality Z = {2a-3b, a,b $\in$ N}

Tags: number-systems

I'm trying to prove that the above sets are equal. The integers can be mapped using the natural numbers and 2a-3b. My thought process is to use induction to prove that you can get positive numbers, all negative numbers, and then 0, but I'm having trouble with the inductive step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $m<0$, set $a=b=-m$. If $m>0$, set $a=2m,b=m$. For $m=0$, set $a=3,b=2$.